# Best software to enable speech-to-text on HTC Desire

Tags: applications, htc-desire, voice-command, voice-recognition

One of the notable features missing from the HTC desire that is found on the Nexus one is the speech to text.

I am using google voice search and am impressed therefore what is the best software (free or paid) to enable the dictation of emails and text messages.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Vlingo: http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.vlingo.client

It learns over time and many people find it more accurate than google's voice recognition.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HTC Desire and speech to text works fine. Are you holding down the microphone keyboard button to the left of the space bar?

Answer (score 0):

Full text to speech is only hidden and can be re-enabled in older HTC versions of android through a keyboard hack. Alternatively you can install goggle voice search just to enable search via voice.

Text to search is fully supported by HTC in the Froyo software update and can be accessed via the keyboard or holding down the search key.